# Windows 7 explorer - PDF thumbnails

Tags: windows-7, pdf

Is it possible to display thumbnails for pdf files in windows explorer? I use sumatra as my pdf reader.

Answer (score 1):

I have Foxit Reader installed on Win7 and I did nothing extra to view thumbnails.
I automatically shows thumbnails for .pdf files...

Comment: If you have adobe reader already installed it, it does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [Handler](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/05/09/foxit-pdf-preview-handler.aspx) for the Explorer Shell.  It can be installed as part of Adobe Reader or Acrobat.

**edit**

Wrong link earlier, which was to the search engine plugin.

Comment: I installed it, nothing happens. Must I install adobe reader too?

Comment: It does not show up on the preview panel? You shouldn't need to restart or anything.